# ComponentWillmount Fetch returning Null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My app is always loading, When i drop a debugger around and add a watch onto variable list & res , i get not available.
I'm not exactly sure what's the problem or am i even debugging it correctly?

please advice. I'm trying to achieve Loaded by loading the json into the list.

**Update:**
I just did a console log and saw data

```
console.log(this.state.list);




    var facemashTab = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      list: [],
      currentIndex: 0
    };
  },
  componentWillMount: function() {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ list: res }));
  },


  render: function() {
     var contents;
      if (!this.state.list.length) {
        contents = (
          <View style={ styles.loading }>
            <Text style={ styles.loadingText }>Loading</Text>
            <ActivityIndicatorIOS />
          </View>
        )
      } else {
        contents = (
          <View style={ styles.content }>
            <Text>Loaded</Text>
          </View>
        )
    }
     return (
      <View style={ styles.container }>
        <View style={ styles.header }>
        <Text style={ styles.headerText }>XXX</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={ styles.content }>
            { contents }
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem, but from my understanding `setState` inside `componentWillMount` will not trigger a render phase ? could you try `componentDidMount`

Comment: Giving me the same result as componentWillMount

Comment: i'm actually learning react from this http://ryanclark.me/going-native-with-react/
just that i'm using JSON instead of them loading off localhost

Comment: I just did a console log and saw data 
console.log(this.state.list);